# Ubuntu 20.04 + Jenkins - access denied and directory does not exists

Tags: 20.04, permissions, java, maven-3, jenkins

I have VSP with Ubuntu 20.04 and Jenkins installed on it. Also have a Java Maven test project which should run as Jenkins job. Few hours ago everything worked well. Then I added one new feature to the Maven project and changed chmod permissions to allow write for groups to the directory where Maven stores the result. And then it crashed. So I tired to set all permissions to 777 but it did not fix the problem. I don't understand how is it possible if all permissions are 777 and it still throws an error permission denied with directory does not exists. Here is the console log:

```
##/home/vlado/selenium-tests/test-1 - is the Maven project directory with chmod 777 


Started by user Vladi Camo
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /home/vlado/selenium-tests/test-1
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /home/vlado/selenium-tests/test-1
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:384)
    at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:674)
    at java.nio.file.Files.createAndCheckIsDirectory(Files.java:781)
    at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:767)
    at hudson.FilePath.mkdirs(FilePath.java:3523)
    at hudson.FilePath.access$1400(FilePath.java:213)
    at hudson.FilePath$Mkdirs.invoke(FilePath.java:1339)
    at hudson.FilePath$Mkdirs.invoke(FilePath.java:1335)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1163)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1146)
    at hudson.FilePath.mkdirs(FilePath.java:1331)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1200)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:637)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:509)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1907)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Archiving artifacts
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
/home/vlado/selenium-tests/test-1 does not exist.
```

I dont understand two lines of it:

```
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /home/vlado/selenium-tests/test-1
and
/home/vlado/selenium-tests/test-1 does not exist
```

Can somebody tell me please what happened there. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem was not in the permissions of project directory but in the permissions of parent directory which missed x perm for others. I don't understand how it happened.